Agent visualization order in NetLogo
I am building a model with two agent breeds. One icon is house and another agent's icon is person. By default the persons are shown over the house icon.

Is there any way to reverse the order of overlapping?
I have tried but no able to find any information regarding the order of the icons being presented. I have tried to change the order of coding also, but that did not work.

What are you looking for exactly? You want it to look like people are entering the house?

The rendering order for agents is determined by breed and then by who number.  From the Programming Guide:

The order in which breeds are declared is also the order in which they are layered in the view. So breeds defined later will appear on top of breeds defined earlier.

As such, if you house breed is defined last, it should appear on top:
breeds [people person]
breeds [houses house] ; breed definition is the last in the code, so house will appear on top

And turtles are rendered in their creation order, with the most recently created turtles being on top as well.
There is no way to control the rendering order for each particular agent, for example to have some people on top of the house and others (who are "higher up" on the map) underneath it.  NetLogo 3D might be an alternative if that's really necessary.

My other answer is still valid, but I thought I'd add a different technique here that popped into my head.
You can control the rendering order of agents by setting them to be hidden? and using stamp to draw them instead of letting NetLogo draw them normally.  Then you have a render procedure, here called draw-agents-in-y-order that you call on setup and go to update the display, making sure to clear-drawing at the start of each go, too.
Example code below, and here is a live version of it, as it's much easier to see what's going on.  Also, note the house shape comment, I had to customize it to make things work a little more smoothly, although it looked okay with the standard house shape.
breed [houses house]
breed [people person]

to setup
  clear-all

  create-houses 10 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ; this model uses a special version of the `house` shape that extends all the way to the bottom, top, and sides
    ; of the shape space, and also has a blank door so agents can be seen "behind" the house.  Without the size change
    ; the people walking around the houses will disappear at apparently too low a coordinate.
    set shape "house2"
    set color (red - 3)
    set size 4
    set hidden? true
  ]

  create-people 100 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "person"
    set hidden? true
  ]

  draw-agents-in-y-order
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  clear-drawing
  ask people [ forward 0.1 ]
  draw-agents-in-y-order
  tick
end

to draw-agents-in-y-order
  ; the size offset is necessary because NetLogo draws the agent shape around the xcor and ycor center
  let agents (sort-on [(-1 * ycor) + (size / 2)] turtles)
  foreach agents [ agent ->
    ask agent [ stamp ]
  ]
end


Thank you for your detailed answer. Its really interesting approach.
